# Tokbox alternative for Multisession Video Broadcasting

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, video-streaming, broadcast, tokbox

I have created a web video Broadcast feature where one will go live and other users will view the same online during the period. We need to have a feature where the broadcaster can add people to share the broadcast screen and the viewer can view both of them on the broadcast. We have used Tokbox for the same. But it is very costly. Can you please suggest on some alternatives that we can try in place of Tokbox.

Your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

`ezTalks` Meetings

```
VSee

Skype
```

their comparison can be found here [Tokbox altenatives](https://www.eztalks.com/video-conference/tokbox-alternatives.html)